# Solving a differential equation with an integrant factor

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I have a math problem described by the next equation:

$\frac{1 - F(x) + (x - \bar{x}) F'(x)}{(1-F(x))^2} - xF'(x)  = 0$

or also can be re-written in one line as:

$1 - F(x) + (x - \bar{x}) F'(x) - xF'(x)(1-F(x))^2  = 0$

$\bar{x}$ is an upper bound of $F(x)$, so can be treated as a parameter. $(1-F(x))^2$ need to read as "(1-F(x)) squared" and should not be confused with the second derivative of $F(x)$.

I have to solve it for $F(x)$ and, I think, it can be solved using an integrating factor (not sure though). I stuck here and any help will be highly appreciated. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

$$1 - F(x) + (x - \bar{x}) F'(x) - xF'(x)(1-F(x))^2  = 0$$
For simplicity $1-F=G$:
$$G(x) - (x - \bar{x}) G'(x) + xG'(x)G(x)^2  = 0$$
$$x'G - (x - \bar{x})  + xG^2  = 0$$
$$x'G - x(1   - G^2)  =-\bar {x} $$
$$x' + x\dfrac {( G^2-1) }{G} =-\dfrac {\bar {x}}{G} $$
Where  $x'=\dfrac {dx}{dG}$ and $\bar x$ is a  parameter.

This is a first order linear DE. Try to solve with [integrating factor method](https://weber.itn.liu.se/%7Ekrzma/DS2017/Integrating%20factor%20method.pdf).

$$\mu (G)=\exp \int \dfrac {( G^2-1) }{G} dG$$
$$\mu (G)=\dfrac { e^{ G^2/2}}{G}$$

Comment: Thank you! But what are further steps to explicitly be solved for $F(x)$?

Comment: Try integrating factor @CoronariasRedig

Comment: I think your initial substitution requires $F'$ to be replaced by $-G'$.

Comment: Yes  you're rihjt Thanks @mcd

Answer (score 0):

You could write $y=1-f(x)$, so that the equation reads $$y-(x-\bar{x})y'+xy^2 y'=0$$ or $$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y}{(x-\bar{x})-xy^2}$$ and hence $$\frac{dx}{dy} +\frac{(y^2-1)}{y}x= -\frac{\bar{x}}{y},$$ which has the integrating factor $\frac{1}{y}e^{\frac{1}{2}y^2}$ and $$\frac{d}{dy}\Big\{\frac{1}{y} 
e^{\frac{1}{2}y^2}x\Big\} = -\frac{\bar{x}}{y^2}e^{\frac{1}{2}y^2}.$$ I don't think you can integrate this explicitly.